# Attempt to rename file in Documents directory has error "file:/..."

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsfilemanager, nsurl

Below is the code I have written to change the name of any file stored in an iOS device "`Documents`" directory.

When renaming the file using this code, the prefix resolves to...

```
"file:/localhost/private/var/mobile/Applications/.../Documents/"
```

instead of the correctly formatted...

```
"file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Applications/.../Documents/"
```

I am losing a slash, and so the rename method fails!!!

I have rewritten this for both `NSString` and `NSURL` formats, and both methods present the identical error. I have tested this using the iOS Simulator and on device, and both tests present the identical error.

I suspect I am overlooking something simple, but cannot figure what it is - any help please?

```
- (void)alterFileNameOrExtension {
    NSError *errorMove = nil;
    NSError __autoreleasing *error = nil;

//note below - entity attribute document.dStringURL has a data type NSString

    NSString *file = [document.dStringURL lastPathComponent];
    NSString *fileName = [file stringByDeletingPathExtension];
    NSString *fileExtension = [file pathExtension];
    NSString *fileNameNew = nil;

//note below - self.tempFileComponent, self.tempFileName & self.tempFileExtension
//note below - are set in the (IBAction) method textFieldDidEndEditing: 
//note below - self.tempFileComponent determines whether the user is attempting to change the file name or the file extension

    if (self.tempFileComponent == 1) {
        fileNameNew = [[self.tempFileName stringByAppendingPathExtension:fileExtension] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    } else if (self.tempFileComponent == 2) {
        fileNameNew = [fileName stringByAppendingPathExtension:self.tempFileExtension];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@ - %@ - attempt to determine tempFileComponent has (possible undefined) E~R~R~O~R: %@_", self.className, NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), error.localizedDescription);
    }

    NSString *filePath = [document.dStringURL stringByDeletingLastPathComponent];
    NSString *filePathNew = [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileNameNew];

    BOOL move = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtPath:document.dStringURL toPath:filePathNew error:&errorMove];
    if (!move) {
        //handle error
    } else {
        //complete process
    }
}
```

## #

With assistance from @Mario, I have adjusted my code and include the working version below for the benefit of others...

## #

```
NSError *errorMove = nil;
NSError __autoreleasing *error = nil;

NSString *file = [document.dStringURL lastPathComponent];
NSString *fileName = [file stringByDeletingPathExtension];
NSString *fileExtension = [file pathExtension];
NSString *fileNameNew = nil;

if (self.tempFileComponent == 1) {
    fileNameNew = [self.tempFileName stringByAppendingPathExtension:fileExtension];
} else if (self.tempFileComponent == 2) {
    fileNameNew = [fileName stringByAppendingPathExtension:self.tempFileExtension];
} else {
    NSLog(@"%@ - %@ - attempt to determine tempFileComponent has (possible undefined) E~R~R~O~R: %@_", self.className, NSStringFromSelector(_cmd), error.localizedDescription);
}

NSURL *fileURLOld = [NSURL URLWithString:document.dStringURL];
NSURL *fileURLPrefix = [fileURLOld URLByDeletingLastPathComponent];
NSURL *fileURLNew = [fileURLPrefix URLByAppendingPathComponent:fileNameNew];

BOOL move = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtURL:fileURLOld toURL:fileURLNew error:&errorMove];
if (!move) {
    //handle error
} else {
    //complete process
}
```

Comment: So, you've surely used a debugger to check at which line the `/` get's lost, did you?

Comment: Just double checked test on device. The slash is lost in the creation of the "filePath" variable... so NSString *filePath resolves to "file:/"... and so the moveItemAtPath: method fails.

Comment: Error description from debugger... Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4.)" UserInfo=0x1da9a850 {NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=file://localhost/private.../Documents/_documents_added/A0516%20%5BA%5D.pdf, NSUserStringVariant=(
    Move
), NSFilePath=file://localhost/private.../Documents/A0516%20%5BA%5D.pdf, NSDestinationFilePath=file:/localhost/private.../Documents/A0516%20%5BA.pdf, NSUnderlyingError=0x1d915290 "The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory"}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The NSString path manipulation methods like `stringByAppendingPathComponent` expects file paths not URLs. It will remove double slashes as this is not a valid file path (although it is a valid URL).

Comment: I have also attempted to use the following code:  `NSURL *fileURLOld = [NSURL URLWithString:document.dStringURL];`  `NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[document.dStringURL stringByDeletingLastPathComponent]];`  
`NSURL *fileURLNew = [fileURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:fileNameNew];`    
`BOOL move = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] moveItemAtURL:fileURLOld toURL:fileURLNew error:&errorMove];`  
with the same errors... am I missing your point?

Comment: I think so. You are still using `stringByDeletingLastPathComponent` which removes "//" inside the string. Convert the string to a NSURL first using `[NSURL URLWithString:document.dStringURL]`. Then use only NSURL methods to manipulate it.

Comment: Thanks @Mario, once I had put a little more thought into your suggestion, this helped me down the correct path. (I was seeking two separate outcomes from the same method and was mixing the code which also confused matters.) As you suggest I have used `NSURL` methods to manipulate the URL "string", then as you suggest convert to store attribute against entity in Core Data. I have included my updated code below to assist others...